# Get group membership of current users using ECMAScript

Tags: client-object-model, javascript, permissions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I determine a user's SharePoint group membership using the client object model?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13306/how-do-i-determine-a-users-sharepoint-group-membership-using-the-client-object-m)

How can I use the client object model to get a list of all (SP) groups the current user is member of?

Larsi

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this? If yes, could you post the answer?