# How to restrict permissions for anonymous user, he should only see the content published in pages

Tags: 2013, publishing, security-trimming

Hi we have internet public website for anonymous users can view without login,
these pages display some reports but still anonymous users can view all site contents and goes to any pages and library of this sites and sub sites.

_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx
Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=

anonymous user should only see the content published in pages only not go inside of site or subsites
How to add anonymous user to group

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two possibilities in this case that doesn't require code.

**1) Change the permission level of anonymous users**
When you change the permission level from "Read" to "Restricted Read" your anonymous user won't see the site contents anymore.

Example - You can add anonymous users to the Restricted Readers group. Or Create a custom group and assign "Restricted read" permission to it.

[image]

**2) Alternate read permission level of anonymous users**
You can simply remove the base permission "View Application Pages" from the "Read" Permission level or create a custom permission level and remove "View Application pages" permission from it by unchecking it as below for anonymous users:

[image]

The "site contents" is not the only place where user will see this navigation option. It is also available through the gear icon on the suite bar. By changing the permissions or permission level it will be hidden from there too.

In the masterpage , you try below code in masterpage:

Find the SharePoint:SiteActions tag, inside it you will find

```
<SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" id="MenuItem_ViewAllSiteContents",
```

change `PermissionsString=""` property to:

```
"EnumeratePermissions,ManageWeb,ManageSubwebs,AddAndCustomizePages,ApplyThemeAndBorder,ManageAlerts,ManageLists,ViewUsageData"
```

Reference - [Hide site content for visitors](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/163966/hide-site-content-for-visitors)

[Security trimming publishing site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/6280/hide-site-actions-view-all-site-content-in-a-2010-publishing-site)

**3)**  Activate the limited access user permission lockdown mode feature

This feature will block users to view list view pages. Users can able to access all other web pages.

In 2010, we had the FormpagesLockDown feature, however, in 2013 we need to activate this feature "limited access user permission lockdown mode".

[image]

Comment: updated answer.

Comment: if i enable lockdown feature is anonymous users loose any features in this internet site?

Comment: and how to add  anonymous users to the Restricted Readers group ? for anonymous what is the user address?

Comment: http://www.expertsupdates.com/ArticleAttachments/sharepoint/enable-anonymous-access-in-sharepoint/Figure8.png 
Check the image. In the SharePoint groups page, you will find this group anonymous user. Click on edit permission and change it to restricted read.

Comment: Also, if you enable this permission, following will happen:

1. Allows anonymous users to only view the Publishing pages, not any of the form or view pages (DispForm.aspx, AllItems.aspx)
2. Disallows anonymous access to pages in the _layouts directory that inherit from LayoutsPageBase.

Comment: you need to logged in as Site collection admin or at least as site owner to modify permission. Also click on the left edit button. See image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JmH5.png

Comment: How to add NT AUTHORITY\Anonymous user to Restricted Readers group?

Comment: The Third one works perfectly,.